# Folder `usr/local/bin` doesn't exists on a MacBook Pro M1 Max, docker can't be installed

Tags: docker, apple-m1

I am trying to install the docker desktop for Mac with M1 Max chip, using the package from the official website - https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac.

After the installation `docker.app` fails to open because of `cannot install symlinks in /usr/local/bin (stage 5)` error.

I have binary file `bin` inside `usr/local` and the only working solution for me was to rename `bin` file to `bin.old` just not to remove it completely and to create a folder `bin`

Then the docker installation succeeds.
What is the correct way of handling this problem?

P.S. I am using `Monterey 12.0` OS version

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` definitely should not be a file. What was the contents of it? Might give some clue about how it got there.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the OS from `12.0` to `12.1` and made a factory reset.
After that `/usr/local` is empty.

This time Docker installed successfully